# Missed Socket Message

Tags: java, c, sockets

I have been doing socket programming for many years, but I have never had a missed message using TCP - until now.  I have a java server and a client in C  - both on the localhost.  They are sending short message back and forth as strings, with some delays in between.  I have one particular case where a message never arrives on the client side.  It is reproducible, but oddly machine dependent.

To give some more details, I can debug the server side and see the send followed by the flush.  I can attach to the client and walk through the select calls (in a loop) but it simply never shows up.  Has anyone experienced this and is there an explanation other than a coding error?

In other words, if you have a connected socket and do a write on one side and a read on the other, what can happen in the middle to cause something like this?

One other detail - I've used tcpdump on the loopback interface and can see the missed message.

Comment: Is your client multithreaded? Is it possible that a separate thread is also select()ing on that message? Also, what OS are you using?

Comment: I don't think its possible for another thread to be selecting on it.  This is on Linux.  Good idea though - I verified with a counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally - after sniffing some more, I found the problem.  Two messages were getting sent before a read (sometimes, but rarely...) so they were both read, but only the first was handled.  This is why it seemed as though the second message never arrived.  It was buried in the receive buffer.

Comment: qrdl makes an excellent point. UDP guarantees 1 write == 1 read, but TCP explicitly does not (to enable better throughput).

Comment: Good point about flow control - that is a great way to prevent this kind of error, but calling bs on my experience is rude.  I almost didn't post the answer since it was such a stupid mistake for just this reason, but I wanted to give anyone else seeing this an idea where to look.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen this happen in SMTP transactions before. Do you have a virus scanner running on that machine? If so try turning it off and see if that makes a difference.

Otherwise, I'd suggest installing [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) so you can take a look at what's actually happening.

Comment: He used tcpdump and saw the missing message. Wireshark gives more details but won't make a big difference.